# Not able to install library(phytools) in R

Tags: r, installation, package

Im not able to install library(phytools) in R,

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘phytools’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please, share the complete set of messages given by `install.packages`.

Comment: Your package depend on 'magick', that is a package than depend on the library libmagick++-dev (in debian). If you have debian try to run: sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev

Comment: thanx man this seems work